# Pygame only working when run from editors

Tags: python, pygame

When I run a Pygame script through an editor such as VSC or IDLE, the script works perfectly fine. When opened with Python through the file explorer, nothing appears. This only happens when I add `import pygame` to the script.

For example,

```py
import pygame
i = 0
while i < 9999:
    print(i)
```

would work only on VSC.

I downloaded and used pip to install pygame, and when I convert to a .exe, it still doesn't run.

Comment: It seems like you have multiple versions of Python installed. You can install pygame in all of them, or you can make sure that you use the VSC installed python from the command line. If you look at the python settings in VSC, it will show the path to the python interpreter it is using. Regarding your problems with exe creation, you'll need to create a separate question with a [mcve]. The most common problems are around file paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment says you likely have multiple versions of python installed.
Probably one you downloaded from python's website or through VSC.

Microsoft Store Python is probably located here:

```
cd C:\Users\<your name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
```

Uninstall that and check your path to python in VSC. Or delete all versions of python, download it anew, and check the PATH box when installing. This will handle the PATH variable for you, and VSC will ask if that's the path you want to use next time you launch it.

Also, you might want to look into using virtual environments. Python3 has this built in and you can create it via the command

```
python -m venv venv
```

then type cd (for powershell/cmd) or source(for bash and Terminal) venv/Script/activate to activate the virtual environment. This way you can avoid installing dependencies globally. When inside the virtual environment you will still use pip to install pygame and other dependencies without breaking you program due to updates.

I'm not sure what causes your .exe issues.

[More about virtual environments here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)